# Define custom serialization/de-serialization for a class

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I am using protobuf-net to serialize/deserialize my objects in my game.

My game is similar to Simcity, and simulates your cities growth. I store this simulation data and load it up again every time the user starts the game.

All works fine, but I would like to reduce the size of my save files. I will be grossly simplifying my code here but I just want to try and get the question across as clearly as I can...:

Every building in the city stores some metadata which describes the type of building it is - what mesh to use to render it, residential capacity, etc. I defined a whole bunch of these StructureDefinition's in my editor. When the game starts, the game manager loads a list of these predefined StructureDefinitions and the simulation will assign a definition to buildings that spawn in the city. So the buildings merely hold a reference to their StructureDefinition's.

Every structure definition has a unique 'ID' value, which is just an integer. Instead of serializing the StructureDefinition for every building when the game saves, it'd be enough to just store the structure definitions 'ID' value. Then, when my object is being deserialized, I take this ID value and request the actual StructureDefinition object from the game manager. All we need to serialize is this single integer. Here is what my class might look like:

```
public class Structure
{
    public StructureDefinition Definition;
}
```

StructureDefintion has a public 'ID' member (`Definition.ID`) There is also a static DataLibrary class which will return the correct StructureDefintion if you call the following static function:

```
DataLibrary.GetStructureDefinition(int ID)
```

I've got everything I need here for it to work the way I want, I just don't know how to do it with Protobuf, or if it is even possible.

Comment: as i understood, you want something, if we represented it in xml will be, '<city name=""><building def="1" location-x="30" location-y="60"/><building def="2" location-x="50" location-y="80"/></city>' ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Though the class should still look like this: 
public class Structure
{
    public StructureDefinition def;
....etc...
}

Comment: That is - I don't want to store the StructureDefinition Id as a separate 'int' that lives inside of 'Structure'. I want to redefine the way StructureDefinition gets serialized so that it is serialized as just an int ("serializedData = this.ID") and is deserialized as "this = DataLibrary.GetStructureDefinition(deserializedData)"

Comment: i think, better to cast your objects to a simple class before serializing and when you load this file, you can translate it to the data you wish with proper loading of real objects, and it would be like, City[Name, List<Building>] and Building class Building[Definition,X,Y] and store it as binary file, which will be faster during load, hope this will help you